# Generating Equal Amount of Random Numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to generate random numbers between 1 and 7 for 420 times in Excel. However, I want every number to appear about the same number of times, about 60 for each. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to generate random numbers (between 1 and 7) 420 times.  Is that the *same* number, 420 times? or 420 different numbers?  Also, if you want every number to appear a certain amount of times, then it's by definition **not** random.  To get the same number to repeat 420 times, you can use `=Rept(randbetween(1,7),420)`.

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **B1** through **B7** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

In **A1** through **A7** enter:

```
=MATCH(LARGE($B$1:$B$7,ROW()),$B$1:$B$7,0)
```

In **A8** enter:

```
=A1
```

Then copy **A8** and paste from **A9** through **A420**

[image]

***NOTE:***

Every cell in **A1** through **A420** has an equal chance of having values from *1* through *7*, but there will be exactly the same number of *1's* as *2's*, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain your second formula? Why did you use MATCH function?

Comment: @Dombey  This match function randomizes the sequence [1-7]